# Нет курсора мыши в убунту сервер в виртуалбоксе

Tags: virtualbox

Сижу на винде десятке, в виртуалбокс поставил убунту сервер и не могу с вывода консоли копировать информацию, так как курсора мыши нет.
Самое интересное, что я настройки никакие не трогал и если убунту 16.04 поставить, то там есть этот курсор.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Причиной тому отсутсвие _иксов_.

Comment: @mkkikи можно это пофиксить как-то?

Comment: Это не ошибка, чтобы ее фиксить. Если вам нужна графика на ОС, то устанавливайте десктоп версию. Если не нужна, а просто надо передавать данные между ВМ и хостом, то выберите удобный для вас способ: запись в файл, к которому имеют доступ обе системы или (лучше) передача по виртуальной сети.